# Android: horizontal LinearLayout does not lay out elements as expected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I create a horizontal LinearLayout that contains an EditText and a button. The button should be as narrow as possible, and the EditText should occupy the entire remaining space.
Like that:

[image: expected]

I write this code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextToSpeak"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/text_to_speak"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveCard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/save_card" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And I get this picture:

[image: actual]

The button is not visible at all, and the height of the EditText has doubled.

How to make these elements look like in the first picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily archive that by using `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_width = "0dp"` in your EditText, so it will take the rest of the space except your button's area.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id = "@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:orientation = "horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/editTextToSpeak"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/text_to_speak"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/saveCard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/save_card" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope that help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use android:weightSum & android:weight. It will give you the ability to fix the sizes either vertically or horizontally.

```
<LinearLayout
android:id = "@ + id/textInputLayout"
android:layout_width = "match_parent"
android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
android:orientation = "horizontal"
android:weightSum="3">

<EditText
    android:id = "@+id/editTextToSpeak"
    android:layout_width ="match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
    android:ems = "10"
    android:hint = "@string/text_to_speak"
    android:inputType = "text"
     />

<Button
    android:id = "@+id/saveCard"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
    android:text = "@ string/save_card" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also be implemented using a Relative layout in android.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextToSpeak"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/text_to_speak"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/saveCard"/>

     <Button
       android:id="@+id/saveCard"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/save_card"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope it helps.)